# Angular Material - Hide disabled select option

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I have a form in my app where I have a `mat-select` with a list of users. Users have permissions and in my select I want to show only those who have permission. I checked the documents for `mat-select` and can disable users but still shown as an option.

I tried to use `[class-hidden]` and try to hide it with CSS, but the space for the user is still there and that looks bad in the app. Is there a way to hide disabled users from select-option?

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="material-input">
  <mat-form-field class="form-group-select">
    <mat-label>User name</mat-label>
    <mat-select class="select" placholder="User names"
      formControlName="user">
      <mat-option  *ngFor="let user of users"
        [value]="user.id" [disabled]="user.permission === 'N'">
        {{user.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the disabled user(s) from `<mat-option>`, would recommend directly filter the element from `users`. Thus, the `users` array will only consist of the user with `permission !== 'N'` and these filtered users will only be displayed in `<mat-option>`.

> .component.ts

```js
// Filter users after getting data
this.users = this.users.filter((user) => user.permission !== 'N');
```

> .component.html

```
<mat-select class="select" placholder="User names" formControlName="user">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">
    {{ user.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

[Sample demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-btsu7z)